# Some parts of the featured image on my website home page is not visible on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4, web-deployment

I am creating a new blog. It uses flask as backend. I am currently using bootstrap template. I have set a image as featured image. On computer it is properly displayed. But on tablets devices it gets cropped out.This is the link to the page I am talking about. [here](https://anygeeks-blog.now.sh/)

I am talking about the image at the very top. Letters of the word LEARN written on cubes.

My question is there any way to get it to automatically resize instead of getting cropped in smaller screens.

The code of that section is

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-3 pt-0 pb-0 bg-lightblue position-relative">
    <div class="pl-4 pr-0 h-100 tofront">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-6 pb-6 align-self-center">
                <h1 class="secondfont mb-3 font-weight-bold">AnyGeeks - A Tech Blog</h1>
                <p class="mb-3">
                    Welcome to AnyGeeks. Here we discuss anything about Tech, Provide Tutorials, Blogging Tips, Game Reviews or anything that involves tech.
                </p>
                <a href="./about.html" class="btn btn-dark">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-md-block pr-0" style="background-size:cover;background-image:url('{{ url_for('static', filename='img/home.jpg') }}')">    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is the fourth line from the last that sets the image. It would be really great if someone could fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should use it as an image with **img-fluid** class, which uses 100% width inside the div, and for the width is calculating the height as auto.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-3 pt-0 pb-0 bg-lightblue position-relative">
    <div class="pl-4 pr-0 h-100 tofront">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-6 pb-6 align-self-center">
                <h1 class="secondfont mb-3 font-weight-bold">AnyGeeks - A Tech Blog</h1>
                <p class="mb-3">
                    Welcome to AnyGeeks. Here we discuss anything about Tech, Provide Tutorials, Blogging Tips, Game Reviews or anything that involves tech.
                </p>
                <a href="./about.html" class="btn btn-dark">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-md-block pr-0" >
                <img src="img/home.jpg" class="img-fluid">  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this property on background image:

```css
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: How do I do that sir ?

Comment: Use this property where you added the background-image, Replace background-size:cover; with this "background-size: 100% 100%;" and one more thing you forgot to add "background-repeat: no-repeat;" property,Please add other wise background image will repeat